# In Minecraft, how do you play in Hard difficulty without depleting hunger?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've been making a Hard map in Minecraft, but whenever I test it, I keep getting hungry! The goal is to kill all of the monsters in the map, but I can't sprint, sleep or focus if I'm about to die of starvation. What do I do?

Answer (score 1):

Try giving the player a saturation potion effect:

```
/effect @p saturation 1000000
```

Comment: Hook it up on a repeating command block?

Answer (score 0):

Some time back I used Mod http://www.dascraft.org/hunger-strike-mod/ for that effect. Not sure is it still supported but it is worth trying

Comment: Link to mod is dead.